# Total Friend of User's Friends?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The friends of friends cannot be retrieved.
But is it possible to get the count (Total No of Friends of friend's friend)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. What you can do is check for mutual friends between a user and each of their friends, which which will give you another statistic which might be useful for your purposes.